# Received nothing after executing AJAX post function

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, ajax, html5

What I'm trying to achieve is to enable users to filter posts based on the selection of the checkboxes located on the sidebar.

I've created a custom post type called projects and a couple of taxonomies such as clients and expertises. I found [this](https://convertintowordpress.com/wordpress-multiple-taxonomy-filter-ajax/) which is exactly what I want to my page to look like with AJAX. However, I think there are some missing code in there. Anyway, I have managed to display all of taxonomies out with checkboxes without any problems.

```
            <!-- Show clients taxonomies in a checkbox -->
            <?php foreach( $myClient as $a ) { ?>
                <div id="cat_id">
                    <input class="client_filter" name="<?php echo $a->term_id; ?>" type="checkbox"><?php echo " ".$a->cat_name; ?>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>

            <!-- show expertises taxonomies in a checkbox -->
            <?php foreach( $expertStyles as $b ) { ?>
                <div>
                    <input class="expertise_filter" name="<?php echo $b->term_id; ?>" type="checkbox"><?php echo " ".$b->cat_name; ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

In my `script.js`, I have the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

/* This function will be called on click event */   
var optionsChecked = function() {

/* initialize all the variables */
jQuery('.filter-result-form').html("");
    var clients = [];
var expertises = [];
var term_id = jQuery('#cat_id').text();

/* loop and push any checked checkboxes into empty array */
jQuery(".client_filter input:checked").each(function() {
    var client_id = jQuery(this).attr('name');
    clients.push(client_id);
});   

jQuery(".expertise_filter input:checked").each(function() {
    var expertise_id = jQuery(this).attr('name');
    expertises.push(expertise_id);
});     

/* collect all the data */
var myData = {
    'filter':1,
    'term_id': term_id,
    'client': clients,
    'expertise': expertises
}

/* Ajax url */
var url = "/mysite/ajax";

jQuery.post( url, myData, function( myData ){
    jQuery('.filter-result-form').append( myData );
});

}

$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).on("click", optionsChecked);

});
```

When I run this code, I see nothing come up in the filter result form. I must admit that I'm still learning about jQuery and AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Wordpress [tutorial](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) on using AJAX in plugins (you are basically adding a plugin to your theme if you need to use AJAX). There are two things I see right off the bat that need to be fixed before your proceed. Note what the tutorial says about the global variable `ajaxurl`. Also make sure you have set up a php function to process the AJAX request, and that you specify that function in the `action` field of your data. It's like you're making a phone call without a phone number; the system doesn't know where to send the AJAX request for processing.

I'd work on anything the tutorial suggests, but I think those two things are the big ones right now.